# How to create table top label that will ignore top margin

Tags: tables

I would like to create table top label as on image below:

[image: Table top label]
The problem I have is that my table fill whole page, so somehow top label would have to ignore top margin. How I can do this? My table is regular:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\multicolumn{2}{r@{}}{KLASIFIKACIJA}   \\
\hline
a   & b                             \\
\hline
% ....
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

???